# Google Maps API: unable to customize marker images when markers imported from KML

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I've googled and googled it. Tried a lot of solutions in the stackoverflow forum     and am posting this question only when I'm totally at a loss.

So what I'm trying to achieve is using a KML file to import location markers. That I'm able to achieve but I keep getting the crosshair kind of icon for the locations not matter however I edit the KML file.

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<kml xmlns='http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1'>
<Document>
    <name>Roundabouts / Traffic Circle Inventory - http://roundabouts.kittelson.com</name>
    <Style id='normalPlacemark'>
        <IconStyle><Icon><href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/red-circle.png</href></Icon></IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark>
        <name>Main St. (I-94 Business)/5th St.</name>
        <styleUrl>#normalPlacemark</styleUrl>
        <description>
            <![CDATA[<strong>Location: </strong>Benton Harbor, MI<br /><strong>Type of Circle: </strong>Roundabout<br /><strong>Status: </strong>Existing<br /><strong>Lane Type: </strong>Single-Lane<br /><strong>Completed: </strong>2010<br />]]>
        </description>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-86.45281,42.11655,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
```

But nothing happens. It still shows the same icon for the marker. If anyone has some ideas/solutions, that would be greatly appreciated. Even a link to the correct stackoverflow link that helps would be greatly appreciated!

Update:
I even tried changing the marker icon for Google's API sample (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml-features) using this html and JS code but still no changes happen to the icon.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>


var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 43.820805, lng: -84.694719},
zoom: 7
  });

  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://www.michiganautolaw.com/geokml/placemark.kml',
    map: map
  });
}

</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

KML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">

<Style id="west_campus_style">
  <IconStyle>
    <Icon>
      <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png
      </href>
    </Icon>
  </IconStyle>
</Style>

  <Placemark>
    <name>My office</name>
    <styleUrl>#west_campus_style</styleUrl>
    <description>This is the location of my office.</description>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-122.087461,37.422069</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the styleUrl in your style

look at this sample

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <Document>
        <name>Luoghi temporanei.kml</name>
        <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin_hl">
            <IconStyle>
                <color>ff0000ff</color>
                <scale>1.4</scale>
                <Icon>
                    <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/coffee.png</href>
                </Icon>
                <hotSpot x="0.5" y="0" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
            </IconStyle>
            <ListStyle>
            </ListStyle>
        </Style>
        <StyleMap id="m_ylw-pushpin">
            <Pair>
                <key>normal</key>
                <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
            </Pair>
            <Pair>
                <key>highlight</key>
                <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin_hl</styleUrl>
            </Pair>
        </StyleMap>
        <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin">
            <IconStyle>
                <color>ff0000ff</color>
                <scale>1.2</scale>
                <Icon>
                    <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/coffee.png</href>
                </Icon>
                <hotSpot x="0.5" y="0" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
            </IconStyle>
            <ListStyle>
            </ListStyle>
        </Style>
        <Folder>
            <name>Luoghi temporanei</name>
            <open>1</open>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Segnaposto senza titolo</name>
                <LookAt>
                    <gx:TimeStamp><when>2014-10-31T13:38:26Z</when>
    </gx:TimeStamp>
                    <longitude>9.887662007021186</longitude>
                    <latitude>45.79797926110749</latitude>
                    <altitude>0</altitude>
                    <heading>-1.925223593789956</heading>
                    <tilt>0</tilt>
                    <range>9224.278715342967</range>
                    <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
                </LookAt>
                <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
                <Point>
                    <gx:drawOrder>1</gx:drawOrder>
                    <coordinates>9.882419515480246,45.79319197443869,0</coordinates>
                </Point>
            </Placemark>
        </Folder>
    </Document>
    </kml>
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Let me give this a go real quick!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to repair/correct my KML file was to import it into Google Earth and then save it again as a KML file, that way it was restructured again the way it was meant to be without any manual work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a KML validator (like [feedvalidator.org](http://feedvalidator.org/))

http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2Fkml%2FSO_20150817.kml

gives the following result:

```
Sorry

This feed does not validate.

line 4, column 0: Undefined kml element: Style [help]

<Style id="west_campus_style">
```

According to the [KML reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference?#container), the `<Style>` tag needs to be inside of a `<Container>` tag.

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20150817a.kml)